# Alert Send_keys function in Selenium doesn't working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, alert

I try to write an answer in alert input.

```
 def solve_quiz_and_get_code(self):
        alert = self.browser.switch_to.alert
        x = alert.text.split(" ")[2]
        answer = str(math.log(abs((12 * math.sin(float(x))))))
        alert.send_keys(answer)
        alert.accept()
```

And also I call it on the other test_page - page.solve_quiz_and_get_code() 
But it didn't print anything in the alert, but after a while, it confirms the alert. Please, help me understand...

Comment: On manual interaction, does the window accept your keystrokes no matter where you click it? Because otherwise, you might have to select a subelement. Can you give me the html that creates the alert box?

Comment: Thank you, I could fix the problem, it was because of CSS selectors.